# Identities For Generalized Harmonic Number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, harmonic-numbers

I have been searching for identities involving generalized harmonic numbers
\begin{equation*}H_n^{(p)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^p}\end{equation*}
I found several identities in terms of $H_n^{(1)}$, but I am looking for some interesting identities for $H_n^{(2)}$. Does anyone know of any identities know of any nontrivial identities for $H_n^{(2)}$?  I found some listed on Wikipedia, but this list is not comprehensive. Thanks for your help.

1. integral identities
2. summation identities
3. recursive identities
4. in terms of another function

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice list and a set of references at [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html).  Additionally, I discovered this one while writing a thesis on the Riemann Zeta function.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(s)}}
 {n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)^2+\zeta(2s)}{2}.$$

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have reference to a proof of that identity would you?

Comment: My Master's Thesis, pages 68-72.  http://thescholarship.ecu.edu/bitstream/handle/10342/4703/Molokach_ecu_0600O_11345.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @user3002473: See the answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351940) question.

Comment: @John:  Thanks for the material, I am looking forward to reading it.  On a similar topic, do you know of series involving the digamma function?

Comment: Check the mathworld site for the digamma function. The last reference there is also a good resource.   http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0387488065/ref=nosim/weisstein-20

Comment: Today's post by John D. Cook is of note. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/07/19/numerators-of-harmonic-numbers/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TheEndeavour+%28The+Endeavour%29

Comment: @John Molokach I like your master's thesis but I'm afraid your nice formula is wrong. Consider s = 2. We have on the one hand from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html formula (18): $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (\frac{H_n}{n})^2=\frac{17 \pi ^4}{360}$, on the other hand your formula gives $\frac{1}{2} \left(\zeta (2)^2+\zeta (4)\right)=\frac{7 \pi ^4}{360}$ which is a different result. And, IMHO, I don't think that the sum for general real $s$ has a simple closed form.

Comment: @John Molokach Don't worry, the formula is ok (at least for s=2), if you correct a typo: you wrote here $H_n^s$ whereas you meant $H_n^{(s)}$. Sometimes the small things matter.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, I didn't think to use the parentheses because of the notation in various literature (including MathWorld) doesn't use it.  (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html for example, where the superscript is used NOT as an exponent.)

Comment: @John Molokach In Mathworld notations are used for functions related to the harmonic number: $H_{n,r}$ for the generalized harmonic number, and $H_n^{(r)}$  for the harmonic number of the order $r$, introduced by Conway. We have been talking here about $H_{n,r}$. I tend to use this notation in the future. The only notation which should definitely not be used - and I hope you agree - is the simple power $H_n^r$ for anything else than the r-th power of $H_n$.

Comment: @JohnMolokach  Can you gentlemen help me answer the question I posed here?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216588/expressions-approximating-generalized-harmonic-number-truncated-polynomials-wit

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze What about you Dr?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a Generalized Harmonic Summation Identity some time ago.

> $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{H_{r} ^{(m)}}{r^m} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( [H_{n}^{(m)}]^2 + H_{n}^{(2m)} \right) \quad ; \quad m \geq 1 $$

I have posted a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351940/strategies-for-summing-harmonic-numbers/1852387#1852387).