# Challenging sum: Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Prove that

> $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}=\frac{101}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac5{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$
>    where $H_n^{(m)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^m}$ is the n$th$ generalized harmonic number of order $m$ and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

This problem is proposed by Cornel Valean and can be found [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2421141851315932&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater).

Here is how I managed to find the integral representation:

We have $\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}$ , then we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}(x^2)^n\ dx\\=\small{-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(x^2)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x^2)-\ln(1-x^2)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^2)-\zeta(2)\ln(1-x^2)-2\zeta(3)\right)\ dx}$$

So any idea how to crack this integral or different approach?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

This result was mentioned by @nospoon [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868355) in equation $(3)$. He didn't post the solution but he provided the idea.

Comment: I would try summation by parts: since
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2} = \frac{\left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^2+H_N^{(4)}}{2} $$
the computation of the original series boils down to the computation of $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$, with a_n being one of the following objects:

$$ \frac{\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2}{n(2n+1)},\qquad \frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n(2n+1)} .$$

Comment: The latter series can be tackled by integration, the former is probably best dealt with  Fourier-* expansions.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio so $a_k=H_{2k}$ and $b_k=\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^2}$ ?  

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k=A_nb_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k\left(b_k-b_{k+1}\right)$$

Comment: The other way around, $a_k=\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^2}$ and $b_k=H_{2k}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio but the first term $A_nb_{n+1}$ will go to $\infty$ .

Comment: You're right, better to take $a_k=\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^2}$ and $b_k=H_{2k}-H_{k}$. The series with $H_{2n}$ replaced by $H_n$ should be simple to evaluate.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio very nice idea. now the first term will converge as $n$ approaches $\infty$. are you going to post a full solution?

Comment: But maybe it is enough to play with the residues of functions like $(\psi(-z)+\gamma)^2$ or $\psi'(-z)$...

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$ you referring to, i think i did it before. I'll check.

Comment: I am not good at complex methods. but all solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We will look into the integral
\begin{align*}
I = &\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin^4 x\frac{ \ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ \mathrm dx
\end{align*} taking the @nospoon's novel approach presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612181/triple-euler-sum-result-sum-k-geq-1-frach-k2h-k-k2-zeta2-zeta3/1868355#1868355). Using the MacLaurin series of [$\arcsin^4 x$](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Arkusfunktionen)
$$
\arcsin^4 x =\frac 3 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2{2n \choose n}}x^{2n}
$$
and the fact that
$$
\small\operatorname{B}(n+\tfrac 1 2,\tfrac 1 2) = \int_0^1 x^{n-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\ \mathrm dx = 2\int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \sin^{2n}\theta\ \mathrm d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4^n}{2n \choose n},\tag{$\small x\mapsto \sin^2\theta$}
$$
\begin{align*}\small
\psi(n+\tfrac 12 ) -\psi(n+1) =&\small \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{\scriptsize k+n} - \frac 1{\scriptsize k+n-\tfrac 1 2} \\
=&\small\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1{\scriptsize k} - \frac 1{\scriptsize k-\tfrac 1 2}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {\scriptsize k} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{\scriptsize k-\tfrac 1 2}\\
=&\small-2\ln 2 -H_n +2(H_{2n}-\tfrac 1 2H_n)\\
=&\small 2(H_{2n}-H_n-\ln 2),
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\Longrightarrow \ {\int_{ 0}^{1 }x^{2n}\frac{ \ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ \mathrm dx} = & \frac 1 4\int_{0 }^{1 }x^{n-1/2} { \ln x \over \sqrt{1-x}}\ \mathrm dx\tag{$\small x^2\mapsto x$}\\
=& \frac 1 4 \left[\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\operatorname{B}(x,y) \right]_{x=n+1/2,y=1/2}\\
=&\frac 1 4\Big[ \operatorname{B}(x,y)\big[\psi(x) -\psi(x+y) \big]\Big]_{x=n+1/2,y=1/2}\\
=& \frac 1 4 \operatorname{B}(n+\tfrac 1 2,\tfrac 1 2)\big[\psi(n+\tfrac 12 ) -\psi(n+1) \big]\\
=& \frac{\pi}2\frac{{2n \choose n}}{4^{n}} \left(H_{2n} - H_n -\ln 2\right),
\end{align*} where $\operatorname{B}(x,y)$ and $\psi(x)$ are the [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) function, respectively, we have
\begin{align*}
I = &\frac 3 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{4^{n}H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2{2n \choose n}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\frac{ \ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ \mathrm dx \\
=&\frac {3\pi}4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}}{n^2}\left(H_{2n} - H_n -\ln 2\right) \\
=&\frac {3\pi}4\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}H_{2n}}{n^2}-\frac {3\pi}4\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}H_{n}}{n^2}}_{=-2\zeta(5) +2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}-\frac {3\pi\ln 2}4\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}}{n^2}}_{=\frac{3}4 \zeta(4)}\\
=&\frac{3\pi}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n}H_{2n}}{n^2} -\frac{3\pi}4\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}}_{=\frac{37}{4}\zeta(5)-4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)} +\frac{3\pi}2 \zeta(5) -\frac{\pi^3}4\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}\\
=&\boxed{3\pi S  -\frac{87\pi}{16} \zeta(5) +\frac{\pi^3}{4}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}}
\end{align*} where $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H_{2n}H^{(2)}_{n}}{4n^2}$ is the sum in question, and the known values of several Euler sums
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}H_{n}}{n^2}=-2\zeta(5) +2\zeta(2)\zeta(3),\tag{1}
$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H^{(2)}_{n}}{n^2}=\frac{7}4 \zeta(4),\tag{2}
$$
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n^4} =& 8\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n}}{n^4}-8\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} H_{n}}{n^4}\\
=&8\big(3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\big)-8\left(\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac 1 2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\right)\\
=&\frac{37}4\zeta(5) - 4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\tag{3}
\end{align*} are used.

*Note:* $(1)$ is in @nospoon's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612181/triple-euler-sum-result-sum-k-geq-1-frach-k2h-k-k2-zeta2-zeta3/1868355#1868355), $(2)$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077016/how-can-we-show-that-sum-limits-n-1-inftyh-n-2-over-n2-7-over4-c/2077560#2077560),  and for $(3)$ you can see [Euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq/469785#469785) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883098/alternating-euler-sums/1883731#1883731).

---

**Evaluation of $I$:** By making substitution $x = \sin \theta$ and using the Fourier series of 
$$
\ln (\sin\theta) = -\ln 2 -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos(2k \theta)}{k},
$$ we get
\begin{align*}
I =& \int_{0}^{\frac\pi 2} \theta^4 \ln(\sin\theta)\ \mathrm d\theta\\
=&\int_{0}^{\frac\pi 2} \theta^4\left(-\ln 2  -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos(2k \theta)}{k}\right)\ \mathrm d\theta\\
=& -\ln 2\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\theta^4\ \mathrm d\theta-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac\pi 2}\theta^4 \cos(2k \theta) \ \mathrm d\theta}_{\text{IBP}\times 4}\\
=& -\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(-\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2} +\frac{3\pi}{4}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^4}\right)\\
=&-\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}+\frac{\pi^3}8\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3}}_{=\frac 3 4 \zeta(3)} - \frac{3\pi}4\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^5}}_{=\frac{15}{16}\zeta(5)}\\
=&\boxed{-\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}+\frac{3\pi^3}{32}\zeta(3) -\frac{45\pi}{64}\zeta(5).}
\end{align*}

---

Combining these, we get the equation
$$
3\pi S-\frac{87\pi}{16} \zeta(5) +\frac{\pi^3}{4}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}=-\frac{\pi^5\ln 2}{160}  +\frac{3\pi^3}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{45\pi}{64}\zeta(5),
$$hence it follows
$$
\boxed{S = \frac{101}{64}\zeta(5) -\frac{5\pi^2}{96}\zeta(3).}
$$

---

**Addendum:** By considering MacLaurin series of
\begin{align*}
\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)
=&-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{ H_{2k}}k-\frac{H_k}{k} + \frac1{2k^2}\right)x^{2k}
\end{align*} and
\begin{align*}
\frac{H_k}{k^2} + \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k} -\frac{\zeta(2)}{k}
=& \frac{\partial }{\partial k}\left[-\frac{H_k}{k}\right]\\
=& \int_0^1 x^{k-1}\ln x\ln(1-x)\ \mathrm dx\\
=&4\int_0^1 x^{2k-1}\ln x \ln(1-x^2)\ \mathrm dx
\end{align*} we have that
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1}\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x) \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}x \ \mathrm dx \\&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{ H_{2k}}k-\frac{H_k}{k} + \frac1{2k^2}\right)\int_{0}^{1}x^{2k-1} \ln x \ln(1-x^2)\ \mathrm dx \\
&=-\frac 1 4\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{ H_{2k}}k-\frac{H_k}{k} + \frac1{2k^2}\right)\left(\frac{H_k}{k^2} + \frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k} -\frac{\zeta(2)}{k}\right).
\end{align*} The integral can be attacked by considering algebraic identity
$$
ab(a+b) = \frac 1 3 (a+b)^3 - \frac {a^3}3 -\frac{b^3}3
$$ with $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$, and extant results.

For the sum, after expanding the summand, the only tricky part is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2k}H_k}{k^3},
$$ which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345073/two-very-advanced-harmonic-series-of-weight-5/3349019#3349019). Then, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2k}H_k^{(2)}}{4k^2}$ can be evaluated by solving the equation obtained.

Comment: Very nice.. good job for doing all these tedious calculations. I'll present my solution soon. (+1)

Comment: @AliShather Thank you :) I'm looking forward to your solution.

Comment: About power series expansions of $(\arcsin x)^m$ around $x=0$, please click the link at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657809.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to establish two relations as Cornel suggested and solve them by elimination.

---

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292603) we have

$$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{H_{2n}}{4n}$ then sum them from $n=1$ to $\infty$ we get

\begin{align}
R_1&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_{2n}}{2n}\ dx\quad \color{red}{x\mapsto x^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}H_{2n}}{2n}\ dx, \quad \color{red}{2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_{n}}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}H_{n}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n}H_{n}}{n}\right)\ dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\left(\underbrace{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}_{\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}+\frac12\ln^2(1-x)+\frac12\ln^2(1+x)\right)\ dx\\
&=\small{\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{x^2\mapsto x}+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\left(\ln^2(1-x)+\ln^2(1+x)\right)\ dx}\\
&=\frac18\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\left(\ln^2(1-x)+\ln^2(1+x)\right)\ dx\\
&=\frac18A+\frac14B\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Let's start with $A$ and by seting $1-x\mapsto x$ we can write

\begin{align}
A&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}\left[\color{blue}{\zeta(2)-\ln x\ln(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}\right]\ dx\\
&=\zeta(2)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1 x^n\ln^3x\ dx-\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(2)}\int_0^1 x^n \ln^2x\ dx\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{(n+1)^3}\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+6\zeta(5)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}+2\zeta(5)\\
&\boxed{A=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\zeta(5)}
\end{align}

where we used $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}=3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac92\zeta(5)$

---

To evaluate $B$, we are going to use the key identity

$$(a+b)^2(a^2+b^2)=\frac23a^4+\frac23b^4+\frac5{12}(a+b)^4-\frac1{12}(a-b)^4$$

and by taking $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ , we get

$$B=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\left(\ln^2(1-x)+\ln^2(1+x)\right)\ dx\\
=\small{\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx+\frac5{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{x^2\mapsto x}-\frac1{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x}}\\
=\frac78\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx-\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x^2}\ dx\\
=\frac78(24\zeta(5))+\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx-\frac16\left(\frac{93}{4}\zeta(5)\right)\\
=\frac{137}{8}\zeta(5)+\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx$$

Since 
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}&=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^4x}{x}\ dx+\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\frac15\ln^52+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1 x^{n-1}\ln^4x\ dx\\
&=\frac15\ln^52+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{24}{n^5}-\frac{24}{n^52^n}-\frac{24\ln2}{n^42^n}-\frac{12\ln^22}{n^32^n}-\frac{4\ln^32}{n^22^n}-\frac{\ln^42}{n2^n}\right)\\
&=\small{4\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{21}2\ln^22\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-\frac45\ln^52-24\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)}
\end{align}

Then

$$\boxed{B=\frac83\ln^32\zeta(2)-7\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac{265}{8}\zeta(5)-\frac8{15}\ln^52-16\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-16\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)}$$

Plugging the boxed results of $A$ and $B$ in (1) we get our first relation:

> $$R_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)\\
> =\small{\frac23\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac74\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac14\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{261}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac2{15}\ln^52-4\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)}$$

---

We have

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-y)}{1-y}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})$$

integrate both sides from $y=0$ to $y=x$ to get

$$-\frac13\ln^3(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$

Now replace $x$ with $x^2$  then multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, also note that $\int_0^1 -x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}$ we get

$$\frac13\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large C}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{2n^2}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$

Rearranging the terms to get

> $$R_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n)^3}-8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}+\frac16C\tag{2}$$

Cornel elegantly calculated the first sum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3345138)

$$\boxed{\small{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}H_n }{(2 n)^3}=\frac{307}{128}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3}\ln ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{8}  \ln ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{15} \ln ^5(2)
-2 \ln (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -2 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}}$$

For the second sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}$$

plugging the common results:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$$

we get

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=\frac{37}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac14\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$$

For the remaining integral $C$, we use the magical identity

$$(a+b)^3a=a^4-b^4+\frac12(a+b)^4-\frac12(a-b)^4-(a-b)^3b$$

with $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ we can write

$$C=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{x^2\mapsto x}\\-\underbrace{\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x}$$

$$C=\frac54\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{4!\zeta(5)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx}_{K}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac{93}{4}\zeta(5)}+\underbrace{2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{J}$$

$$C=\frac{27}{4}\zeta(5)-K+J\tag{3}$$

we have already evaluated $K$ above:
$$K=4\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{21}2\ln^22\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-\frac45\ln^52-24\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)$$

for $J$

$$J=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1+x}\ dx$$

using [the rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293274)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ax\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\ dx=(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{a+1}}{n}$$

allows us to write

\begin{align}
J&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\ dx-\ln2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x}\ dx\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n H_n\int_0^1x^n\ln^3x\ dx-\ln2\left(-\frac{21}4\zeta(4)\right)\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}+6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(n+1)^4}+\frac{21}{4}\ln2 \zeta(4)\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^4}-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)+\frac{21}{4}\ln2 \zeta(4)
\end{align}

Plugging

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}=\frac78\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\zeta(5)$$

we get

$$J=\frac{279}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Plugging the results of $K$ and $J$ in (3) we get

$$\boxed{\small{C=24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+24\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac3{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{21}2\ln^22\zeta(3)-4\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac45\ln^52}}$$

and by substituting the boxed results in (2) we get our second relation

> $$R_2=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n} }{(2 n)^2}(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})
> =\frac78\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+5\zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3} \ln ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{4} \ln ^2(2)\zeta (3)\\ -\frac{2}{15} \ln^5(2)
> -4 \ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

---

Thus

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}=\frac{R_1-R_2}{2}=\frac{101}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac5{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

and as a bonus

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^2}{(2n)^2}=\frac{R_1+R_2}{2}\\
> =\small{\frac{421 }{64}\zeta (5)+\frac{9 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{2}{3} \ln ^32\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{4} \ln ^22\zeta (3) -\frac{2}{15} \ln^52-4 \ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

---

**Note:**

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973408) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236084).

Answer (score 3):

Update: the details may be found in the preprint [The evaluation of a special harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336148969_The_evaluation_of_a_special_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n?fbclid=IwAR0l5IHWlch50VYofVcdRYijjvGw0btgGcKqcCaSe3iVlwAbQjmNjU_E49Y)

**The magical way by Cornel Ioan Valean**

By the Cauchy product, we have $\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2) \log(1-x^2)= 3\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 n}}{n^3}-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } x^{2n}\frac{H_n}{n^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } x^{2n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}$, and if we multiply both sides by $\log(1-x)/x$, and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, using that $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-H_n/n$, and doing all the reductions, we arrive at

$$2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n} H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n)^2}-12\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^4}+12\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n^4}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^3}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log \left(1-x^2\right) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x+2 \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(-x) \log ^2(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x\\+2 \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n^2}{n^3}+2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}\\-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_n^{(2)}}{n^3},$$
where the last integral is given here [Two very advanced harmonic series of weight $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345073/two-very-advanced-harmonic-series-of-weight-5/3345138#3345138), and all the last resulting harmonic series are given in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. The reduction to the last series has been achieved by using the identity, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log^2(1-x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$. The series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^3}$ maybe found calculated in the paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonicseries with a weight 5 structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type H_{2n} by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055_On_the_calculation_of_two_essential_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n).
Thus, we have

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}=\frac{101}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac5{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3).$$

All the details will appear in a new paper.

Comment: Cornel's solutions are always unique.